# Why does Laravel give error in SQL query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If this query is executed in my database directly:

```
select * from `account_transactions` 
    where `AT_createuser` = 4 group by `AT_transactionficheno`
```

But this returns en error:

```php
Transactions::with('type')->where('AT_createuser', JWTAuth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('AT_transactionficheno')->get();
```

Error is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'fee.account_transactions.AT_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from
>   `account_transactions` where `AT_createuser` = 4 group by
>   `AT_transactionficheno`)

Comment: you can [`->toSql()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) to see the actual sql query being generated by that eloquent query. perhaps we can start from there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to go to config/database.php
on mysql > strict => false